# Powering an ESP32 from a car 12V supply

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, esp32

I'm confused.

The datasheet seems to say 3.3v, but I read (e.g., https://techexplorations.com/guides/esp32/begin/power/) that one may apply up to 12V to the 5V pin.

However the car runs at about 14.5V with the engine running.

So:

- Will it work to power the ESP32 directly from the car?
- Will a voltage regulator do or will it get too hot?
- If a voltage regulator won't do then it'll have to be a buck converter, right?
- Are there any microcontrollers (preferably with Bluetooth and CAN) that can be powered directly from a car?

Comment: A car is a nasty noisy environment, you may get spikes to 160 V when heavy loads turn off. Get a buck converter, preferrably one that's rated for a car, otherwise one that goes to well over the nominal 14 V.

Comment: Will it really be so variable in the mini-ISO connectors?

Comment: Is the mini-ISO connected by a fuse to the 12 V, or connected to a regulator? If the former, yes, there's the possibility of large spikes. You'd be surprised what fixed car equipment is specified to. Continuous -12 V and +24 V (for inept people jump-starting) and load dump spikes to 160 V. Non-engine related equipment should work down to 8 V, and engine running equipment down to 5 V. Removable equipment probably doesn't need the jump-start protection, but whether you protect against load dump is a question of how lucky you feel.

Comment: Just curious, guys, since you know this stuff: Will a 12V zener protect from voltage spikes in a car then?